# c# string .Startwith() any string from List<string>

Tags: c#, string, list

I have a list of strings in example:

```
['xxx', 'xxxyy', 'ccccy']
```

and a normal string i.e. `String example1 = "xxxyyy"`

And I want to check if any of the strings in my list matches start of my example1
I dont need to know which strings match but only if example1 starts with any of the strings in the list.

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?

Comment: Hint: LINQ is really helpful for this sort of thing, particularly the `Any` method in this case....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ for that like this:

```
if (yourArray.Any(a => example1.StartsWith(a))
```

Comment: This does exactly what I needed, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the below simple method using `foreach` loop.

you should also handle the `null` cases here.

```
private static bool StartsWith(string example1, string[] yourArray)
{
    if(example1 == null || yourArray == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    foreach (string str in yourArray)
    {
        if (example1.StartsWith(str))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```